# error after setting up firebase and pods

Tags: ios, firebase

I followed the firebase offical guide to set up my podfile.
However I now get this error when I try to run my app:

> ld: library not found for -lPods
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the `.xcworkspace` file after running `pod install` or `pod update`, not the `.xcproject`.

It should have been generated by the pod command, and will contain both your regular project and the CocoaPods project with the dependencies in.